# How to modify a html page after running javascript functions

Tags: javascript, runtime

I am trying to modify webogram runtime. webogram is an online web-based messenger. So, for example, I wrote a javascript code to change the name an element runtime. But, some elements come after clicking on some objects-, for example, after you click on the search button then you will see a new div in HTML code which has not been before!.. how can I catch these elements and modify them by GetElementbyId and other javascript methods?  To make it crystal clear, I need to get information about all contact list. Normally when you click on a contact name then you can see this information such as last seen and ... But I want to write a javascript function to click automatically on all of the contract lists and obtains their information. I hope you understand my meaning!

Comment: Is this for a chrome/browser extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window.setTimeout to execute a function after a certain delay. So, you could do something like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('yourbutton');
el.click();

// execute the function below after 500 milliseconds
setTimeout(function() {
  var contacts = document.getElementById('contacts');
  // do something with contacts     
}, 500)
```